# Camera Overlay Image Is squished on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

So it seems that because of the menu bar on the right hand side of the gui, the overlay I'm adding is being squished.  The image I'm getting from the artist is a square, but once the overlay is applied inside the camera it is no longer square.  What do I have to do to get the image to be applied for the whole screen, or what must I do to get the square to appear as a square in my app?  Any ideas about how to get over this problem would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Sincerely,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was an Xcode issue, but it turns out I was subtracting 100 from the width because of a problem I was previously solving.  Sorry for wasting your time on this one- the problem was in my code.